# HTML input text box vs CakePHP Automagic Form Elements

Tags: cakephp

I was manually creating a simple form with one input text box field like this:

```
<form action="/user/add" method="post">
<input type="text" name="data[user_id]" value="1">
```

But when I call `$this->model->save($this->data)` in the Controller,
nothing was saved to the Table.

Only when I used this and the data in the field was written to the database successfully:

```
$form->create(null, array('url' => '/user/add'));
echo $form->input('user_id', array('label' => 'User ID', 'value' => '1'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create the form manually,the name of the input part should be

```
<input type="sometype" name="data['modelname']['fieldname']" value="somevalue">
```

And in your code that should be

```
<form action="/user/add" method="post">    
<input type="text" name="data['User'][user_id]" value="1">
```

See [automagic form elements](http://book.cakephp.org/view/189/Automagic-Form-Elements) in the cookbook.

Comment: +1, You should look at the source of the working code, and see for yourself what the form elements are named. And you do need to create a form anyhow!